# Trigger alert in prometheus/grafana for timestamp from node-exporter too old

Tags: grafana, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

We've got node_exporter running, and I am using the textfile collector to let me put in a timestamp of a file modified by a job.

The metrics output:

```
# HELP job_timestamp_file Metric read from /usr/local/etc/node_exporter/job-timestamp.prom
# TYPE job_timestamp_file untyped
job_timestamp_file 1.567657381e+09
```

So we've successfully collected that in prometheus.  What my prom guy and I are having problems with, both being pretty new to prometheus and grafana, is how to write the query to trigger an alert if

current-epoch-time - job_timestamp_file > 86400

Which really seems like it ought to be easy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time() - job_timestamp_file > 86400`

The node exporter also exposes the mtime of the files it reads via the textfile collector.